# "Except for the main house" in my sentence

Tags: word-usage

Should I use "except for" or "except" in my sentence?

"There are three additional cottages in the yard. Except the main house tourists can stay in any of them."

I found a similar example like mine: "They all came except Matt."
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/except_1?q=Except

And in this discussion as well: "Everyone except John likes the movie."
https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/excluding-except-john.1188027/

Answer (score 3):

The question is a subtle one and the answer is not simple.

It appears to depend largely on the positioning of **except** in the sentence, whether a noun precedes or follows it, and how it's being used (preposition, conjunction,).

Grammar Today says:  **Both "except" and "except for" are correct after a noun**:

Another source quotes The Advanced Learner's Dictionary of Current English: **"Except for" is required when what is excluded is different from what is included.**

Similar guidance comes from Quora (below)

In your example, **Except** precedes the noun and the main house is different from the three cottages.

So, according to these rules, **"Except for" the main house.....** is required.

This also seems to me to be the idiomatic way of phrasing the sentence.

Numerous longer explanations and examples are given in the sources.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/except-or-except-for
https://academic.oup.com/eltj/article-abstract/XXXV/3/260/545193?redirectedFrom=PDF
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-except-and-except-for-in-terms-of-their-usage
https://www.myhappyenglish.com/free-english-lesson/2013/12/11/except-vs-except-for-confusing-english-vocabulary-lesson/

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry, I don't understand this explanation: "Except for" is required when what is excluded is different from what is included." Could you please explain?

Comment: What is excluded is **the main house**; what is included is **the cottages**. The explanations and illustrations given in the sources will give you a better idea of the guides to the usage.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: I also have another sentence: "Except the main house, guests can stay in the little house made of bamboo." This is a little house so it's different from the main house. So again "for" is required. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.