# "Except" vs "except for"

Tags: word-choice

I was studying the difference between "except" and "except for" and noticed that in different sources they use them interchangeably in similar examples.

> 1. "Everyone was tired except for John."
> 2. "Everyone was ready except John."
> 3. "Except for Louisa, who away in Berlin this weekend, we'll all be at the party."
> 4. "We all went except Tom."

If "except for" is used when what is excluded is different from what is included then why don't they use "for" in sentences #2 and #4?

But in #4 it is required. Perhaps it's according to this definition: "If "except for" is used when what is excluded is different from what is included." As in Louisa is different by not being with the group.

Comment: See the answer to an earlier question on this subject:    https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274037/except-for-the-main-house-in-my-sentence/274053?noredirect=1#comment510934_274053

Answer (score 7):

In all four of your examples, "for" is optional in normal usage.

In spoken English, it would commonly be dropped, whereas in formal written English it is slightly more likely to be retained, but no-one is likely to misunderstand either way.

Answer (score 4):

We often include the preposition ***for*** after ***except*** when it's used in the ***not including*** sense. Note that we *rarely* do this with ***excepting*** (an alternative form<sup>1</sup> that's becoming less common over time).

It's largely just a stylistic choice, but the main factor affecting whether we include ***for*** or not is the "distance" between the actual word ***except*** and that part of the text identifying the cases that ***aren't*** being excepted. In OP's example #4, that's the word ***all***, which is only separated from ***except*** by the single-word verb ***went***.

In effect, including ***for*** is a courtesy to the reader, to help him parse the text. When the reader encounters ***except***, he knows he'll have to link this to ***two different noun phrases*** (the "excepted", and the "non-excepted"). The presence of that *optional* preposition (before the "excepted" identifier) can often serve as a gentle "nudge" to the reader to pay slightly more attention, *because the "non-excepted" category isn't necessarily "nearby" in the text*.

In OP's example #3, there's quite a bit of text between ***except*** and the "non-excepted" category it references *(**all**)*, which is why most people would be much more likely to include ***for*** there, whereas they wouldn't do this with example #4.

---

EDIT: In a comment below, OP asks why his unspecified source says ***Both** [including "for" or not] **are correct after a noun.*** I assume the reason "noun" is specifically mentioned there is because of examples like ***Her face is attractive except for an unsightly mole**.* Regardless of whether we think of the "non-excepted" element as being the entire 4-word assertion, or just the adjective ***attractive***, it's obviously not a noun. And in *that* context, you *must* include the preposition ***for***.

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't recommend learners using ***excepting*** (it's a bit dated / stilted) themselves in these contexts, but [here's an NGram link](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22We%20all%20went%20excepting%22) to several written examples of ***We all went excepting** [whoever **didn't** go]*.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question, if you please. Why does it say  "Both are correct after a noun: "I  like all fruit except (for) oranges." (excluding oranges). Which noun are they taking about "fruit" or "oranges"?

Comment: I don't know where you got that "Both are correct after a noun" from, but it's inspired me to add an extra section to my answer, which I hope will enlighten you. Obviously in *I like all fruit except (for) oranges*, the word ***except*** comes AFTER the NOUN PHRASE ***all fruit***. And for an example like that, your source is quite correct in saying that the sentence is valid *with or without the word **for***. Which is NOT the case with *Her face is attractive except for an unsightly mole* (where you ***can't*** validly omit ***for*** AFTER an ADJECTIVE).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time and writing another explanation. I appreciate it.

Comment: I got it from: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/except-or-except-for. Thus there are two cases when "for" is compulsory. The one mentioned above in your explanation regarding the distance. The longer the distance is between "except" and "for" the more confusing it may be to understand the text. (I am rephrasing what you said to make sure I don't misunderstand you)and the second case:  "Another source quotes The Advanced Learner's Dictionary of Current English: "Except for" is required when what is excluded is different from what is included." Do I understand correctly?

Comment: You're definitely right about that "distance" business. And rephrasing is an *excellent* approach in such contexts - it forces you to juggle with the concepts until you have a clear understanding, *and* it provides "verifiable" evidence for someone like me to be able to confidently say *Yes, you've got it!* As to that "when what is excluded is different from what is included", I'm not sure exactly how to interpret that. Obviously my "unsightly mole" is "different" because it's a ***noun*** being "singled out" from a "not excluded" context that isn't even a noun in the first place...

Comment: ....so maybe that's all it means ("different" = "different **part of speech**"). It's not obvious to me that ***for*** is "mandatory" in, say, *All the city's inhabitants were evacuated except [for] the extraterrestrials.* But surely the implication there is ***humans*** were evacuated, but not ***aliens*** - even though they're *extremely* different. So unless someone else has any different opinions, I'm going to say the *only* principle is a matter of when the "included" and the "excluded"  are "far apart" (in terms of "intervening text" ***and/or*** different ***syntactic*** functions).

Comment: Thank you once again for such an interesting discussion!   It's definitely a matter of style as you have said before. Your example shows that  "for" is optional before"extraterrestrials." While the source quoted above says it is compulsory. I think we English learners should take each possible option into account especially when there is more than one correct option.

Comment: I don't have access to The Advanced Learner's Dictionary of Current English, but if you think it's telling you that ***for*** is "mandatory" in my "extraterrestrials" example, I'd be pretty sure you've misunderstood what they're saying. Or I suppose it's *feasible* they have made a mistake. I certainly haven't! :)

Comment: No, I meant it says it is compulsory in a similar example like yours about two things being different not about different parts of speech. Or do I misunderstand? I am sorry I had to reask but could you please share your opinion again?.https://academic.oup.com/eltj/article-abstract/XXXV/3/260/545193?redirectedFrom=PDF

Comment: The authors of that ELT Journal publication aren't actually native speakers. They're trying to *derive* relevant syntactic rules by studying example utterances, which is different to what ***I'm*** doing (consulting my "inner grammarian", who can't really be "wrong", because I'm a competent native speaker). Imho they're actually just making the situation more complicated than it really is. The actual "rule" (such as it is) really is what I essentially summarised as *The more "separate" the 2 categories (excepted and non-excepted) are, the more it becomes **necessary** to include "for"...*

Comment: ...where my concept of "separate" includes examples like #1 ***Except for John, everyone is ready***. Native speakers would normally include ***for*** there, even though they usually *wouldn't* with the "natural sequence" version #2 *Everyone is ready except John*. That's because the non-standard sequence #1 "prioritises" the task of figuring out what the two referents of ***except*** are going to be (initially we don't know ***either*** of them). Since the ***only*** thing we know at first is "two different things are going to be introduced soon", fronting tends to amplify that difference.

Comment: ...in short, it's probably simplest if you just think of (optional) ***for*** as a convention / device that mostly just means "pay special attention to make sure you fully understand what's included and what's excluded by the word ***except*** as used here".

Comment: "Imho they're actually just making the situation more complicated." Exactly! I was quite confused when I read it. Your explanation is short and clear.

Comment: "That's because the non-standard sequence #1 "prioritises" the task of figuring out what the two referents of except are going to be (initially we don't know either of them). Since the only thing we know at first is "two different things are going to be." Sorry but could you please rephrase it for me?  :/

Comment: Normally by the time we encounter the word ***except*** with this sense, we've ***already*** read the "non-excepted" referent (which *normally* appears in text that could be a perfectly valid standalone sentence that would still be meaningful even if *nothing* was "excepted"). If the word ***except*** is "fronted", that gives us a "marked" (not what we expected) utterance - which *on average* conveys something like ***Pay attention**!* to the reader. And the reader ***will*** have to pay attention, because the utterance doesn't use "standard default phrasing".

Comment: Thank you so much! You answered each question I had. I appreciate your help. By the way I didn't know the writers of that article aren't native speakers

Comment: I initially *inferred* the fact that the authors (LI CHIU-MING, HSI CHING-HUA) aren't native speakers from the names themselves. But armed with that initial suspicion, I've looked *very carefully* at the actual text they wrote. There's absolutely nothing syntactically "wrong" with it, but lots of choices of phrasing are just very slightly "unusual" (and the text meanders randomly between a "formal, academic" register and a more "chatty" style, which I simply wouldn't expect from native Anglophone professors or the like).

Comment: Thus what should be my rule of thumb? The first principle regarding the distance between "except" and "for" and the second one,   as you said: "in short, it's probably simplest if you just think of (optional) for as a convention / device that mostly just means "pay special attention to make sure you fully understand what's included and what's excluded by the word. " Let me rephrase the last explanation. I should pay attention which word "for" defines. Again probably in order not to lose the link between "except" "for" and the word which is excluded not included.

Comment: You seem to be assuming the syntactic principles here are far more "fixed" than is really the case. It's just a preposition, that *in context* doesn't really mean anything at all. There are many contexts where with ***or*** without ***for*** is perfectly okay for all native speakers, but there will also be plenty of contexts where people disagree over what's "natural" and/or "correct". Perhaps a really simple "rule of thumb" might be *Always include "**for**" except in short sentences* (which could in principle be phrased as *Always include "**for**" except **for** in short sentences!* :)

Comment: I see. Thanks a million!

Comment: Hello. I was wondering if you have a blog or if you write articles for students as some teachers do and share them online. I am asking because you explain really well and obviously did your best to explain the confusing difference to me. If you have a page I would love to subscribe to it. :)

Comment: Nah. I'm only really here (and the sister site ELU). Incidentally, I've only just seen your earlier question on this same issue. Where your example sentence is actually invalid/poor quality English (because ***them*** has no identifiable referent; there's no contextually-established "collective category" that could include the cottages *and* the main house). So it's not really true to say that you need ***for*** because the cottages and the main house are "different". Putting aside the fact that it's somewhat "invalid", you need ***for*** primarily ***because of the "fronting".***

Comment: Oh, thanks. But some native speakers agreed with that example. I am not arguing of course. :)

Comment: I'm not saying I significantly *disagree* with what Ronald Sole posted! I'm saying that you're wasting time and effort trying to understand "the rules" to this level of detail! ~It's not like some "God of English Syntax" set down all the relevant rules like Moses's god wrote down the Ten Commandments. There are some *imprecise* principles & guidelines, better known to some people that to others (plus we don't all necessarily agree on what those rules are / should be). If you think Ronald and I disagree, you're probably "over-analysing" the situation.

Comment: OK. But what should a non-native speaker do? If I know rules I am unlikely to make a mistake. I was studying German and French. That principle worked there. Perhaps it doesn't work with English? You said I am wasting my time. That scares me.:) What would you rather have a student do?

Comment: If you include the word "for" ***every single time*** you use "except" in such contexts, I don't think there's ever likely to be an occasion where a "descriptive" (not "prescriptive") linguist would say what you wrote was actually ***wrong, invalid***. There are some ("short & simple") contexts where it's ***possible*** to omit it, and there are some other contexts where it's ***not acceptable*** to omit ***for***. But if you want a clear-cut, easily understood ***and*** easily remembered rule that will always "work", I suggest you just go with ***Always include "for"***.